# declaring variables inside \pgfmathdeclarefunction

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to speed up my `pgfplots` (2000 samples per curve). One thing that causes them to be slow is that (unless pgf has a built-in optimizer) pgf is computing certain values multiple times. To illustrate the problem, consider the following example where, I believe, pgf will compute the logarithm of `#1` twice.

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{sincos}{1}{\pgfmathparse{
    sin(log(#1))+cos(log(#1))
}}
```

While `log(#1)` might be sufficiently fast, imagine it is a complex custom function I declared with `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`.

How would one change sincos so it computes the logarithm of `x` only once? Could one declare something like a local variable? Maybe with `\pgfmathsetmacro`?

The solution should take into account that pgfplots is switching to pgf's fpu implementation when evaluting functions.

Comment: `\pgfmathdeclarefunction{sincos}{1}{\pgfmathsetmacro\thelog{log(#1)}\pgfmathparse{sin(\thelog)+cos(\thelog)}}`. This is not necessary faster if Lua backend is enabled.

Comment: Do not forget that you can `externalize` a tikzpicture. This will save your time once and for all.

Comment: I have made use of `\pgfmathsetmacro` as suggested and I was able to accelerate the generation of a single diagramm from 11 seconds to 8 seconds. That's a whopping 27% improvement. I'm already externalizing the pictures, but I'm using the preview package to generate a single PDF with all plots in it.

Comment: It takes lualatex 8.7 seconds to generate a single diagram while pdflatex does it in 8.1 seconds. Do I need to manually enable the lua backend?

Comment: Update: I had pgfplots set to `compat=1.8` which doesn't enable the lua backend by default. I changed that and I also tried `\pgfkeys{/pgf/luamath=parser}`, but lualatex is still lower than pdflatex by a considerable amount.

Comment: I read that the lua backend doesn't like macros. So I avoided the macros by declaring helper functio. For example above, I would pass the logarithm as an argument to a helper function which then computes the sum of the sinus and cosinus. This didn't help either, lualatex is still slower than pdflatex.

Comment: LuaLaTeX is slower to compile a basic document than pdfLaTeX generally. It has more overhead. I think @Symbol1's point was not that switching to LuaTeX would necessarily speed things further, but that the use of the variable would not necessarily speed things at all, if LuaTeX is being used. 8 or 10 seconds is not long. LuaLaTeX takes longer than that on my machine just to think about possibly reading the code. But if you need a lot of computations, the overhead becomes proportionately smaller  and overall compilation may be faster. But LuaLaTeX is not necessarily faster for arbitrary cases.

Comment: The question should take into account the desirability of providing an MWE.